# How to prove this modular criterion for prime numbers of the form $p=2^n \pm a$?

Tags: prime-numbers

How to prove following statement :

> For prime numbers $p$ greater than $3$, it is true that:
>
> if $p=2^n-a$ and $a\equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$
>
> if $p=2^n+a$ and $a\equiv 5 \pmod 6$ then $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$
>
> if $p=2^n-a$ and $a\equiv 5 \pmod 6$ then $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$
>
> if $p=2^n+a$ and $a\equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$

Maybe some conclusions from my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81900/15660) could be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing the fact that $2^n =2,4 \mod 6$ and that $p \neq 0,3 \mod 6$ solves them..

Comment: following your hint I have proved statement...thanks